# How to debug a null pointer exception for Android Rect class

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to port a java game to Android using eclipse, however, I'm stuck at trying to debug the collision detection system. I use "java.awt.Rectangle" for the game's collision detection system, and it runs fine on an Applet, but when I convert it to "android.graphics.Rect", the app returns this in the logcat:

09-24 16:23:07.047: E/AndroidRuntime(15845): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.graphics.Rect.left' on a null object reference

Can someone please tell me what this means, how to debug this, and what's wrong with my code? (Shown below)

EDIT: After making changes, I discovered that "Rect.intersects" is not working for some reason. No collision is recognized by the two rectangles.

If it helps, I was following the tutorial from "http://www.kilobolt.com/day-7-creating-an-android-game-from-start-to-finish.html"

```
private int x;
private int y;
private int speedY;
protected boolean visible;
protected Rect r;

public Shoot(int startX, int startY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    x = startX;
    y = startY;
    speedY=-14;
    visible= true;
    r = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

public void update() {
    y += speedY;
    r.set(x, y, 15, 15);
    if (y < 0) {
       visible = false;
       r = null;
    }
    else if (y < 750) {
        checkCollision();
    }
}

private void checkCollision() {
    //detects collision
    if (Rect.intersects(r, GameScreen.basket.getBounds())) {
        visible = false;
        GameScreen.score += 1;
    }
}
```

(code below is from the basket class)

```
public Rect getBounds() {
    //Creates Rectangle boundaries for collisions
    return new Rect(240, 73, 15, 15);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to write :

```
if (y< 0){
   visible = false;
   r = null;
} else if (y < 750){
    checkCollision();
}
```

and not

So adding **else** you do not check on a **null** object.

```
  if (y< 0){
   visible = false;
   r = null;
  }
  if (y < 750){
    checkCollision();
  }
```

Alternatively you can change *checkCollision()* by adding a non-null check.

```
private void checkCollision(){
 //detects collision
 if (r!=null && Rect.intersects(r, GameScreen.basket.getBounds())){
    visible = false;
    GameScreen.score +=1;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This removes the null pointer exception, but now the collision detection doesn't work at all. The object doesn't disappear and the score doesn't increase.

Comment: The collision detection works for y>0 and y<750, you don't want that ?

Comment: For some reason the collision detection is just not working for me. When the two objects meet nothing happens.

Comment: You can add some print statements to console in order to check if checkCollision is executed and when

Comment: After imputing print statements, I discovered that for some odd reason, the "Rect.intersects" does not work. In other words, no collision is recognized.

Comment: I figured it out. The coordinates for my Rectangle were off. In android it's left, top, right, bottom, unlike Java's Rectangle class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to do this, look a the `else`:

```
if (y< 0){
       visible = false;
       r = null;
}
else  if (y < 750){
       checkCollision();    
}
```